# Windows 10 installation wizard puts Reserved System Partition on non-booting disk

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, windows-installation

I am trying to install Windows 10 in my new laptop (Lenovo [Legion Y530-15ICH](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/legiony530-15ich_y530-15ich-1060_y7000p_y7000p-1060_hmm_201901.pdf)) ([user guide](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/legiony530-15ich_legiony530-15ich-1060_ug_en_201806.pdf)), it has an M.2 SSD and a HDD.

When I got to the screen to select the disk where to install the OS, I select my SSD and hit "Next", then it tells me the usual, that it is going to create a partition and so on. I found out when reviewing that instead of making the system partition on the SSD, it has put it in the HDD.

How may I make the Windows 10 installer to create the system partition on the SSD? I know there are some question related to moving such partition if installed incorrectly, but because I am doing a fresh installation I would prefer to do it correctly from the start.

P.S.: I have checked another questions similar to mine, but they do not seem to answer it. And yes, I can probably disconnect the HDD and install Windows, but I would prefer not to dismantle the laptop.

P.P.S.: I want to do it this way, because I've already tried ignoring it and while Windows works, when I try installing Ubuntu to dual-boot, the boot loader does not seem to work and it only boots Windows.

Comment: Done, sorry for the lack of information

Comment: If no better answer presents itself, pages 32, 34, and 42 of the hardware maintenance manual (first web link added into your question) show how to disconnect the HDD without removing it; Detach the hard disk drive connectors in the directions shown by arrow 1 on page 42, then stop and go no further.

Comment: @K7AAY Thank you, I ended up doing that. I also did a system image in case something happens and I have to reinstall the OS so I don't need to take apart de computer.

Answer (score 1):

There's **two** questions to be addressed here:
1) Installing Windows (10) to a chosen drive, and
2) Trouble(s) installing Ubuntu after Windows.

In both cases there are *many* moving parts.

Windows installation writes to the first 512k of the drive, and also to the `(P)MBR` to take control of the drive and to mark it as "active". I suspect that you have a `(U)EFI BIOS`, and quite possibly a "boot order" in your `BIOS/Firmware Settings` that is counter intuitive to the (install) direction you hope to obtain.

When the Windows installer detects an `(U)EFI BIOS`, Windows will create an `EFI` partition on your drive, which instructs your computer to boot to the installer, and finally Windows after installation. If you do *not* have your *desired* target disk selected as your *first* disk within your `BIOS`. This could easily explain your dilemma.

Ubuntu's installer, generally, treats Windows far better than the Windows installer treats Ubuntu. If Windows is installed first, and correctly. Ubuntu's boot loader [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html)  will *replace* changes Windows makes to your hard drive, and add Windows to its "Boot Menu", which allows you to choose to boot *either*.

In the end. I believe if you wipe the drive of both Ubuntu and Windows, go into your BIOS/Firmware Settings, and pick your SSD to boot from before it tries your other hard drive, then reinstall Windows before Ubuntu, you'll achieve the results you're hoping to.

**NOTE** `HTH` is NOT my signature. But an indication that I **H**ope **T**his **H**elps (an acronym common in Forums, and Mailing Lists)

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try changing the order in the BIOS.

Comment: I tried changing the order in the BIOS but for some reason it seems that it resets, not sure why. I ended up disconnecting the internal hard drive, installing Windows in the SSD and reconnecting it again, and I did a system image in case something happens not to need to take apart the laptop again. Thank you for your answer, very well explained.

Comment: You're *very* welcomed! Very odd that it rejected your chosen boot order. Maybe the topic of another adventure? ;)

Comment: Tbh, when I change the order and re-enter the BIOS, the order is changed, but once I enter the installer, if I cancel the installation and go back to the BIOS order is once again the original, and it is not that resets the configuration, so yeah, I'll probably ask in the future, but for now I'm going to finish installing and configuring my laptop. Thanks